# How to Expand an HTML table sideways left and right in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table, margins

Given a simple table that is a child of an article.

The table has a 100% width so it fits its article parent.
I want the table to expand a little out, side ways both left and right, in a symmetrical way.

In my code the table does expand nicely on the *left* side, however it does not react to anything I set in CSS on the *right* side.

(*Notice that the left text is nicely aligned with the text that is outside of the table, despite the table having margins set.*)

The left side works perfectly, but the right side does not.
What I want to achieve is for the right side of the table to expand in the same way outward and towards the right, a few pixels.

What have I overlooked here? Thanks!

[image]

```css
body,
html {
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 60px;
  width: auto
}

article {
  background: #DDD;
  width: auto
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0 -10px 0 -10px;
  /* Expand the Table on both left and right side */
}

th,
td {
  padding: .5em 5px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

table td {}

table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.today {
  background-color: #FFD700
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #FFD700
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <article>

    Start<br> Start
    <br> Start
    <br>
    <br>

    <table>
      <tbody id="weekdagtabel">
        <tr id="day-1">
          <td>Maandag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-2">
          <td>Dinsdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-3">
          <td>Woensdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-4">
          <td>Donderdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-5">
          <td>Vrijdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-6">
          <td>Zaterdag</td>
          <td>Gesloten.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-0">
          <td>Zondag</td>
          <td>Gesloten.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br> End
    <br> End
    <br> End
    <br>
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually *want* the table to be 100% width. You want 100% plus whatever negative margins you add to the parent.

```css
body,
html {
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 60px;
  width: auto
}

article {
  background: #DDD;
  width: auto
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: calc(100% + 10px + 10px); /* Add the negative margins from below */
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0 -10px 0 -10px; /* Expand the Table on both left and right side */
}

th,
td {
  padding: .5em 5px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

table td {}

table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.today {
  background-color: #FFD700
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #FFD700
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <article>

    Start<br> Start
    <br> Start
    <br>
    <br>

    <table>
      <tbody id="weekdagtabel">
        <tr id="day-1">
          <td>Maandag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-2">
          <td>Dinsdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-3">
          <td>Woensdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-4">
          <td>Donderdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-5">
          <td>Vrijdag</td>
          <td>08:00 tot 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-6">
          <td>Zaterdag</td>
          <td>Gesloten.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-0">
          <td>Zondag</td>
          <td>Gesloten.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br> End
    <br> End
    <br> End
    <br>
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```